# Create macOS High Sierra and newer bootable recovery partition on a separate standalone disk

Tags: macos, partition, recovery

There are manuals on cloning the recovery partitions to a separate disk for any macOS or OS X version prior to High Sierra, but I can google nothing about creating a standalone recovery disk for High Sierra and higher.

Is it possible for APFS based macOSs? Are there any manuals?

Comment: If these manuals exist, then how about providing a link to a few of them?

Comment: For example: https://www.lifewire.com/create-os-x-recovery-hd-on-any-drive-2260909

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest is no longer possible with Big Sur. When booting to Recovery, you are required to enter a password of an existing account. AFAIK, these passwords are not stored in the Recovery volume. This would make it impossible to boot from a standalone Recovery disk.

Before Big Sur, there is no reason the an AFPS Recovery volume could not be placed on a standalone disk. However, getting the firmware to boot Recovery from such an arrangement might require a third party boot manager such as rEFInd. I an unaware of any manual which would explain how to do this. On the other hand, I can not imagine a reason one would want to do what you are proposing.